# parsing JSON data and plotting using d3 in playFramework

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, playframework-2.0

I am new to playframework javascript so please excuse me if the questions seems very basic.

What I am doing is very trivial.

Using the Application Controller I read a txt file which looks like this

```
 {[  12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  21,  32,  45 ]}
```

in my controller I define a Action to return json.

```
  var sourcedata = Source.fromFile("Agregation.txt")
  var linesdata = sourcedata.mkString
  def jsondata = Action {
      Ok(Json.toJson(linesdata))
  }`
```

I make a AJAX call from my view to jsondata through this

```
var listdata = $.get('/jsondata',  function(data) { 
        return data;
    });
```

this returns the json object which i verified using curl.

```
        curl --include http://localhost:9000/jsondata
        HTTP/1.1 200 OK
        Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
        Content-Length: 88
```

My aim is to plot these points using d3 in bar chart or just lines , but I am unable to convert this json object to a javascript object or anything that d3 can use.
Can you please suggest me how to go forward from here.

Comment: Have you tried to use `d3.json()`?

Comment: @ChristopherChiche I figured out the problem that i was facing , actually the way I am storing listdata is wrong. in the success call back of the ajax  call i manipulate the data now whick works fine !